# String assignment of ref. to string object to memory happens after this statement?

Tags: java, string

**why is this?**

```
String str1 = "one";
String str2 = "two";
System.out.println(str1.equals(str1 = str2)); // false, doesn't assignment of ref. to string object memory location happens after???
System.out.println(str1.equals(str1 = str2)); // true, same statement
```

I was asked this in a mock interview and yet I still don't get it.

Comment: As a clarification why this question is far more complex than you anticipate after the first glance: The statement `str1 = str2` is executed before the `equals`, right? So wouldn't the  `equals` return `true` if both `str1` and `str2` now hold the same `String` reference? Interestingly, it returns false.

Comment: This is actually a good question. But in my opinion, this question is only theoretical, as I recommend to always write assignments as standalone statements, and not as part of an expression.

Comment: It's certainly an _interesting_ question, but I don't know if I'd call it a _good_ question in an interview context. Knowing the answer from experience might not reflect well on the interviewee's code style.

Comment: @ChrisBouchard This is a good interview question. If you know the semantics of Java this is trivial to answer.

Comment: @idmean, I'd say it's an okay question, not a great one,  for an entry level position.  Beyond that, it's not a good question at all

Comment: @ChrisBouchard being able to argue for the answer is what makes any question usable for interview. This one looks pretty reasonable to see how one is able to take statements apart and explain how they are executed. Unlikely to be answered by most as shown by this question), but looks short and complex enough for triggering the discussion. Unlike Kevin I don't expect true entry level candidate to answer, only those who actually are/aspire to move higher likely to answer.

Comment: I personally would hope that the candidate's first answer is, "this code will never execute, because I won't let it pass code review". After we've put this out of the way, we can discuss the finer points of Java execution.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I just feel like there are better ways to start a conversation that _don't_ put the interviewee on their back foot (and show how clever the interviewer is). This is a quirk of evaluation order — either they already know it, they happen to think of it, or they don't know. I'd prefer to ask them to talk about a time they solved a difficult problem through research, so they can speak from experience.

Answer (score 30):

I think the answer is in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7) that describes the Evaluation Order in point 15.7. Generally this is done from left-to-right. In your case the evaluation will be

1. load str1 (from `str1.equals`) -> `"one"`
2. load str2 (from `str1 = str2`) -> `"two"`
3. store value to str1 (from `str1 = str2`) -> str1 is now `"two"`
4. the value of the complete expression `str1 = str2` is `"two"`, but remember that for this statement the str1 was already loaded in the first step. It will not be loaded again.
5. invoke equals on `"one"` (which was already loaded, see above) with the parameter `"two"` -> false

You can also have a look at the decompiled Java Code (run `javap -c ClassName` on your classpath) which will kind of show you this order as well:

```
       0: ldc           #7                  // String one
       2: astore_1
       3: ldc           #9                  // String two
       5: astore_2
    [...]
       9: aload_1           // <-- loads the value of str1
      10: aload_2           // <-- loads the value of str2
      11: dup
      12: astore_1          // <-- stores to str1
      13: invokevirtual #17 // <-- invokes equals
```

What this does not do is load the value of str1 again after storing to it.

The language specification has some more examples of edge-cases and how they are handled (like "what happens if one of the arguments of a function is a function that throws an exception).

Comment: That's interesting. In general then (not in this case since `String` is final) those two method calls could run completely different methods — if `str2` were an instance of a subclass assignable to `str1`, and the subclass overrode `equals`.

Answer (score 8):

Java specification [15.12.4. Run-Time Evaluation of Method Invocation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4), governs this.
It states; "At run time, method invocation requires five steps. First, a target reference may be computed. Second, the argument expressions are evaluated. ..."

So we first compute the target and then evaluate the arguments.

The target expression in your example is `str1`, which prior to evaluating the arguments will evaluate to a specific string object.  So we call the `Equals` method on that object.  At this point we no longer care about the variable str1, and the fact that we change the object that this variable points to when evaluating the arguments is irrelevant.

Answer (score 7):

In my first answer, I stated that each of these lines could be broken down into 3 individual statements: the assignment, the `equals`, the `println`. However, this produced different bytecode and thus, my claim was wrong.

Here is what happens internally, demonstrated using the byte code that the 3rd line of OP's snippet produces:

```
   0: ldc           #2                  // String one
   2: astore_1
   3: ldc           #3                  // String two
   5: astore_2
   6: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   9: aload_1
  10: aload_2
  11: dup
  12: astore_1
  13: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
  16: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
```

The noteworthy part here is that the `aload_1` in offset 9 stores the initial value of `str1` on the stack. Offsets 10, 11 and 12 then perform the reassignment, but the value on the stack is left untouched and thus still contains the old reference.

That is the reason why str1.equals(str1=str2) is false.

I guess this is prime example why inline assignments should be avoided.

Comment: Meh, you beat me to it. :-D Then I'll just drop my link to the java language specification here. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7

Comment: @Boris no, your answer is far more elaborate. Please upvote Boris' answer, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

```java
// ref, str1 refers to string object "one"
String str1 = "one";
// ref, str2 refers to string object "two"
String str2 = "two";

// 1. "one".equals(str1 = str2): replace str1 with ref value which is "one"
// 2. "one".equals("two"): ref str1 is assigned with ref str2, so str1 now refers to "two"
System.out.println(str1.equals(str1 = str2)); // false

// 1. "two".equals(str1 = str2): replace str1 with ref value which is "two"
// 2. "two".equals("two"): same as №2 previous step
System.out.println(str1.equals(str1 = str2)); // true
```

Comment: Yes but why is the "prev ref" used for the equals? `str1` gets changed by a. , then why is the new ref not used in b.?

Comment: @f1sh I have updated the answer with more clear explanation

Comment: wouldn't you expect the `str1=str2` to happen before evaluating the `str1.equals`?

Comment: Good point. No, but I cant proove it now; have to dig into JVM spec

Comment: @f1sh No, I wouldn't expect that. Would you expect `null.equals(a -> { println("oops"); return "abc"; })` to output "oops" before throwing an NPE?

Comment: @daniu that is different as it is involving a lambda which first needs to be executed, which never happens in your example. So no, that would never output anything.

Comment: @daniu take a look at this example: https://ideone.com/XAh0l0 - this is basically your example, but the lambda is executed. This **does** print the output and then the NPE.

Comment: ...and [this example](https://ideone.com/0WRAPL) proves that the lambda gets executed and str1 gets reassigned, but the NPE happens anyways. That is the interesting part of this whole question/issue, the explanation is in the bytecode though, see Boris's answer

Comment: @f1sh You're right, it was a bad example; the term in brackets of course is executed in both cases. In yours, `str1 == str2` after that line as well obviously.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
        if (this == anObject) {
            return true;
        }
        ....
 }
```

Short answer: in the first statement `this` holds "one", therefore operates on the 'old version' of `str1`, even if the object changed in the meantime.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit more? The `equals` is not put on the call stack before the reassingment of `str1`. So the `this` is not a constant. Right?

Comment: @f1sh see my answer;  The target of the invocation is evaluated before the arguments so while you are correct that equals is not put on the call stack the value of `this` is selected before the assignment of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
L1: String str1 = "one";
L2: String str2 = "two";
L3: System.out.println(str1.equals(str1 = str2)); // false, doesn't assignment of ref. to string object memory location happens after???
L4: System.out.println(str1.equals(str1 = str2)); // true, same statement
```

in L3 you compare str1 with the newly assigned value, but compare to the 'old' one, therefore false

in L4 you compare to the new one, and as both are now the same it's true

Comment: Yes, but why? str1 gets changed by the `str1 = str2` statement, only then is the equals executed. What part of the JLS specifies that the "old str1" has to be used for the equals?